# Error when trying to install Node Express

Tags: node.js, proxy

I am trying to install node express by running `npm install express -g` but I get this error in the console window. I have set the

> HTTP_PROXY - http://:@my-proxy:8080

And...

> no_proxy - localhost, 127.0.0.1

Error

```
C:\>npm install express -g
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm ERR! Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
npm ERR!     at errnoException (dns.js:37:11)
npm ERR!     at Object.onanswer [as oncomplete] (dns.js:124:16)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 5.1.2600
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "express" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd C:\
npm ERR! node -v v0.8.21
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.11
npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: looks like dns can't resolve registry.npmjs.org.  Can you ping that address from that box?

Comment: I am not very sure what you are trying to do with the proxy settings, but basically, the npm installer can't access registry.npmjs.org.

Comment: @Munim I am not trying to do anything with proxy settings. My PC connect to internet from behind a proxy. All I am trying to do here is install node express module but I think the proxy are not allowing it to connect (but thats my guess).

Comment: @bryanmac all I get when I try to ping that url is                  C:\>ping registry.npmjs.org
Ping request could not find host registry.npmjs.org. Please check the name and try again.

Comment: Looks like you're being blocked by your proxy.

Comment: Are you using the proxy as given or you have removed username/password

Comment: Thanks guys for your comments. The issue was I had a '#' in my password so the HTTP_PROXY variable with http://(username):(password) got messed up because of that.

Comment: @kapricanon wow, that's a pretty interesting catch. I had a similar issue with a website once. They didn't properly encode the URL variables, so I couldn't login!

Comment: the issue with '#' was killing me .. such a nice find .. if there any article related to issue with npm and special characters ?